# Why isn't CodeceptJS executing the steps in my test? And why can I not see the test being executed?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, codeceptjs

I've recently come across CodeceptJS and I thought of giving it a try. I was following the tutorial on the [CodeceptJS's QuickStart page](http://codecept.io/quickstart/) but now I'm facing two issues:

1. The test seems to execute only the first step
2. I don't see the execution of the test

The following is when I run `codeceptjs init`:

[image]

The following when I run `codeceptjs run --steps`:

[image]

The following is my test (Test101_test.js):

```js
Feature('Google search');

Scenario('test something', (I) => {
    I.amOnPage('/');
    I.fillField('q', 'Codeception');
    I.see('YAY');
});
```

Log from selenium server:

> 17:29:38.490 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities
>   [{rotatable=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@35f1c325,
>   browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true,
>   requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.6.2,
>   url=http://webdriver.io}}]]) 17:29:38.496 INFO - Creating a new
>   session for Capabilities [{rotatable=true,
>   locationContextEnabled=true,
>   loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@35f1c325,
>   browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true,
>   requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.6.2,
>   url=http://webdriver.io}}] 17:29:38.871 WARN - Exception thrown
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Build info: version:
>   '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700' System
>   info: host: 'My-Mac-mini.local', ip: '172.20.4.68', os.name: 'Mac OS
>   X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.(DefaultSession.java:119)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:36)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:189)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:222)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:184)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:150)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Build info: version:
>   '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700' System
>   info: host: 'My-Mac-mini.local', ip: '172.20.4.68', os.name: 'Mac OS
>   X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:96)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.newInstance(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:64)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:209)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:86)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to
>   the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system
>   property; for more information, see
>   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be
>   downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases   at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:37)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:95)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:277)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:135)
>     ... 14 more 17:29:38.875 WARN - Exception: The path to the driver
>   executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;
>   for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The
>   latest version can be downloaded from
>   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Could someone help me find what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you started a Selenium server and the correct driver to control Firefox?

Comment: @skAstro Yes, I did. I forgot to include the logs for that but updated my question with them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just encountered the EXACT SAME problem, I had to type "Selenium-standalone install" and then "selenium-standalone start" in my command prompt.  I then opened another command prompt and typed "codeceptjs run --steps" and this time the tests all ran properly, instead of just running the first one, as happened to you.  I hope this helps, I found this issue very frustrating!

Comment: Thanks!!! I was using the selenium server standalone jar to start up the selenium server. I got the server via NPM after seeing your comment and now it works. I'm curious though, what if I was (hypothetically speaking) restricted to the jar alone? Is there a way to get it to work then?

Comment: Glad I was able to help!  I got very spoiled using WebDriverIo's test runner to handle winding Selenium up and down for me, and totally forgot I had to start it manually to take codeceptjs for a run.  With regards to your follow up question, I'm not sure.  I still have a lot to learn about the finer points of how jar files and java-related things in general work.

Comment: Would this maybe help? [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone-wrapper)

Comment: I can relate. On my first attempt I too didn't start the server nor am I very familiar with running jar files. Thanks again